# Как организовать модальное окно

Tags: php, ajax, корзина

Есть очень древний сайт, в котором корзина товаров организована таким образом:
На шаблон страницы массивом выводятся все товары с их данными. Под каждым товаром есть кнопка «Купить», с ссылкой на `"/корзина/&?id = {$idтовара}"`, то есть ссылка GET-параметром передает id товара на обработчик корзины, а в обработчике идет запрос к БД с id товара на вывод цены, параметров и т.д.

Нужно сделать модальное окно с подтверждением добавления товара в корзину при нажатии на кнопку «Купить», где будет указан товар с двумя кнопками: «продолжить покупки» и «перейти в корзину».

У меня была идея перевесить ссылку на кнопку «перейти в корзину», но нужно чтобы товар передавался в корзину при нажатиии на «Купить», а не просто всплывашка появлялась. А если на кнопке «Купить» оставить ссылку, она будет сразу перебрасывать в корзину.

Как можно малой кровью решить вопрос, чтобы товар добавлялся в корзину и всплывашка вылезала, но не перебрасывало по ссылке при нажатии на «Купить»?

Можно конечно заморочиться и методом POST отправлять формы AJAX-ом в обработчик, а из обработчика уже доставать POST массив и по нему строить запрос к БД, но очень не хочется менять логику обработки запросов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно делать GET-запрос AJAX-ом на ту же страницу `"/корзина/&?id = {$idтовара}"` по клику на «Купить» и показывать всплывающее окно, логику тогда менять не придётся.

Comment: Тоже уже погуглил, что можно отправлять через GET и как, спасибо за совет

Comment: А не подскажите как можно решить данную проблему?
Описание: Шаблон вывода товаров построен на выводе товаров в разметку циклом, через смарти.
Хочу сделать всплывашку, но выводит только для первого товара.
разметка такая 
<div id="modal_cart" class="modal">
<div class="modal_content">
<div style="position:relative">
<h3 style="display: block;text-align: center;">{$data[i].name}</h3></div>
<img class="lazy" data-src="/show/{$data[i].image}?150" width="150" height="121" alt="{$data[i].name}" itemprop="image"/>
</div> </div>

Все это прописал внутри {section name=i loop=$data}{/section}

Comment: Извините что так отформатировалось, но смысл таков. Хотел чтобы для каждого товара выводил фотографию товара при нажатии на кнопку под товаром('Купить'), с id="btn_modal_cart". Но выводит как я уже сказал только первый товар. 
Была идея чтобы в JQuery вставлять смарти переменную с id товара, чтобы выводилось определенное модальное окно для каждого товара, на кнопку сделать так id="btn_modal_cart{id}", на форму сделать так id="modal_cart{id}", и если нажимается опр-ая кнопка, выводится опр-ая форма для товара с индивидуальным id. Но не могу передать смарти в jquery функцию.

Comment: Путем опытным пришел к этому
var id =  {/literal}{$data[i].id}{literal};
var modalcart = document.getElementById("modal_cart"+id);
var btncart = document.getElementById("btn_modal_cart"+id);

В консоли выводит все элементы для которых есть id="modal_cart{$data[i].id}", но когда нажимаю на кнопку показа пишет что свойство null, ну это габелла уже